# How do I include one header file in multiple .go files?

Tags: go, cgo

I've got one header `foo.h` and two source files `main.go` and `bar.go`.

`foo.h`contains two functions: `foo()`, `bar()`

In `main.go` I am calling `C.foo()`, in `bar.go` I am calling `C.bar()`.

Both import pseudo-package "C" and `#include "foo.h"`

Although I added include guards to `foo.h`, I am getting the following error:

In function `foo`: `/path/too/foo.h`: multiple definitions of `foo`

Likewise for function `bar()`

Comment: How are you building your package?

Comment: `go build github.com/path/to/pkg/main`  and all of those files are in `package main`

edit: editing path to package main

Comment: i actually did that, i just commented incorrectly.

Comment: the error says you have "multiple definitions" when including `foo.h`, but a header should only have declarations. Check the contents of the header file.

Comment: the ```foo.h``` contains multiple headers, in particular some ```winnt.h``` and ```intrin-impl.h```, which are not defined by me